HADOOP_ORG.APACHE.FLUME.TOOLS.GETJAVAPROPERTY_OPTS: invalid variable name
hadoop@Master:~$ flume-ng version
/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/hadoop-functions.sh: line 2360: HADOOP_ORG.APACHE.FLUME.TOOLS.GETJAVAPROPERTY_USER: invalid variable name
/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/hadoop-functions.sh: line 2455: HADOOP_ORG.APACHE.FLUME.TOOLS.GETJAVAPROPERTY_OPTS: invalid variable name
Flume 1.11.0
Source code repository: https://git.apache.org/repos/asf/flume.git
Revision: 1a15927e594fd0d05a59d804b90a9c31ec93f5e1
Compiled by rgoers on Sun Oct 16 14:44:15 MST 2022
From source with checksum bbbca682177262aac3a89defde369a37

.bashrc:
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk8
export JRE_HOME=${JAVA_HOME}/jre
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=${HADOOP_HOME}/lib/native
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=${HADOOP_HOME}/lib/native"
export SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/spark
export HBASE_HOME=/usr/local/hbase
export FLUME_HOME=/usr/local/flume
export FLUME_CONF_DIR=$FLUME_HOME/conf
#export FLUME_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=/usr/local/hadoop/lib/native"
export JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH=${HADOOP_HOME}/lib/native
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH
export PYTHONPATH=${SPARK_HOME}/python:${SPARK_HOME}/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip:${PYTHONPATH}
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3
export PATH=$PATH:${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${HADOOP_HOME}/bin:${HADOOP_HOME}/sbin:${SPARK_HOME}/bin
:${FLUME_HOME}/bin:/usr/local/scala/bin:${HBASE_HOME}/bin
export CLASSPATH=.:${JAVA_HOME}/lib:${JRE_HOME}/lib:$(hadoop classpath):$(hbase classpath)
:${FLUME_HOME}/lib/*
export TERM=xterm-color

How to solve this flume warning, I found a lot of information can not solve.
version:  hadoop3.1.3  hbase2.2.2  flume1.11.0
I tried to install other versions of flume, such as Flume 1.7.0 and Flume 1.9.0, and the results were the same.
If you have a solution, please let me know. Thank you!

configuration content
'flume-env.sh:  export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk8'
'hbase-env.sh:
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk8
export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=true
export HBASE_OPTS="$HBASE_OPTS -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"
export HBASE_DISABLE_HADOOP_CLASSPATH_LOOKUP="true"'

Please don't add comments to clarify; [edit] your question instead
